# Update Id Primary Key field with C#

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq, primary-key

Hai, like the title.. I just wanna make sure how if I want to update primary key in LINQ? I did google and found that it`s impossible to update Id in Linq. the other way is I delete the old record and insert new but the problem is it will be not effective if the table has a relationship with other table..maybe someone give me a better way to solve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Changing the Primary Key will break all relationships so I don't know what you mean by "the problem is it will be not effective if the table has a relationship with other table"

Comment: Why do you need to change PK?

Comment: Like m.edmondson said, don't do that as it's simply wrong. Explain what's your final goal and maybe there's correct way to achieve this.

Comment: How the primary is getting generated on database?

Comment: dear All, thanks for advice..I just wanna make sure..regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are dependent rows in another table then you either need to enable the ON UPDATE CASCADE option on the foreign key constraint(s) OR you need to update TWO rows simultaneously. Otherwise you will get a constraint violation error.